# Find $\alpha$ for this dice rolling game.

Tags: probability, statistics, solution-verification

There is the point $A(10)$ on the number line. Let's following the die rolling game rules like below with its pips are $1$ to $6$ as commonly we've known.

- The 1st rule) A point moves as much as $+2$[positive direction with magnitude 2] for the even pips like $2,4$ and $6$
- The 2nd rule) A point moves as much as $-1$[negative direction with magnitude 1] for the odd pips like $1,3$ and $5$.

After doing this trial $100$ times, "$A$" lied on the right direction compared with $90$. We get $P(Z\geq \alpha)$ considering the continuity correction. Find the real number $\alpha$. (Z is the random variable following normal distribution.)

From here, **my solution starts**. Let the $X_i$ be the movement of a point for $i$th trial (Here Each $i$, $1\leq i \leq 100$)

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
X_i & 2 & -1 &  \\
\hline
p(X_i) & 1/2 & 1/2 & 1 \\\end{array}
$$

From the table I got $E(X_i)= \frac{1}{2}$ and $V(X_i) =\frac{9}{4}$

So only have to consider is $X(=X_1 + X_2 + ... +X_{100}) >80$, Plus $E(X) = 50$ and $V(X) = 15^2$

Therefore $P(X\geq 80.5) = P(Z\geq \frac{80.5-50}{15}) $ from continuity correction for $P(X>80)$. (In other words,
$\alpha = \frac{61}{30}(=\frac{30.5}{15})$ )

The answer sheet claimed the $\alpha = 2.1$. I can't find any errors in my solution. Please let me know which points did I wrong.

p.s.) **The answer sheet solution.** (The reason why the author claimed $2.1$).

Say Y be the number of the even pips doing the $100$ times trials, Then only just find $P(10+2Y-(100-Y) > 90)$

In other words $P(Y\geq 61)$. Since the $Y$~$B(100,1/2)$, $P(Y\geq 61) = P(Y\geq 60.5) = P(z\geq 2.1)$

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $P(Y>60) = P(X>90)$. The difference only comes into play when you add the continuity correction factor. The standard deviation of $X$ is three times as great as the standard deviation of $Y$ (because the distance between $-1$ and $2$ is three times as great as the distance between $0$ and $1$). Therefore the continuity correction on $X$ is $\frac13$ as significant as the continuity correction on $Y$.

So I would say that both the "official" answer ($\alpha = 2.1$) and your solution ($\alpha = 2.03333...$) are reasonable approaches, with the difference being due to the relative importance of $1$ unit of $X$ compared to $1$ unit of $Y$.